# python manage.py syncdb não funciona!

Tags: python, sqlite, django

Ao tentar seguir um [tutorial](http://www.pythonize.org/blog/criar-api-rest-django/)

**Não consigo continuar porque o banco não foi criado, pode me ajudar?**

Erro:

```
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Comment: Se utilizar o comando `help`, como recomendado, qual é a saída?

Comment: Anderson, aparecem várias palavras reservadas mas nenhuma delas é syncdb, encontrei outros posts que tem o mesmo comando com syncdb, por isso, resolvi postar aqui. Imagino que pode ser algo faltando no meu ambiente ou algo parecido.

Comment: Na sessão anterior, "Criando um projeto Django", é usado o comando `python ../manage.py`, enquanto nesse é apenas `python manage.py`. Os dois arquivos existem?

Comment: Sim existem, o manager.py está no primeiro diretório webserver, tentei executar python ../manage.py syncdb, dá o mesmo erro. Tentei voltar um nível no diretório, dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Achei a resposta[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685931/unknown-command-syncdb-running-python-manage-py-syncdb], o syncdb foi removido é para usar migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, o comando correto é:

```
./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

ou

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

[image: Comando run-syncdb]

Comment: Valeu Victor, como havia funcionado nem me preocupei de verificar no manual.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

encontrei a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685931/unknown-command-syncdb-running-python-manage-py-syncdb)

O comando syncdb foi retirado do Django, agora use migrate.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Testei aqui e funcionou!!!